# How to Iterate over too big ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java

I have two ArrayList sourceMessageList and TargetMessageList. I need to compare both the message list data.

Now lets say List1 - 100 Records. List2 - 1000 records
From List1- 1st record is compared with each record in list2 and then List1- 2nd record is compared with each record in list2.

But list2 is getting the value hasNext() to true for 1st source data in list1.

```
private void compareMessageList(ArrayList<String> source_messageList, ArrayList<String> target_messageList)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Iterator<String> sourceMessageIterator = source_messageList.iterator();
        Iterator<String> targetMessageIterator = null;

        while (sourceMessageIterator.hasNext()) {
            String sourceMessage = (String) sourceMessageIterator.next();

            targetMessageIterator = target_messageList.iterator();
            while (targetMessageIterator.hasNext()) {
                String targetMessage = (String) targetMessageIterator.next();
                if (getCorpValue(sourceMessage).equalsIgnoreCase(getCorpValue(targetMessage))) {
                    assertXMLEquals(convertSwiftMessageToXML(sourceMessage), convertSwiftMessageToXML(targetMessage));
                }
            }
        }

        if (buffer.toString().length() > 0) {

            writeDifferenceTofile(buffer.toString());
            buffer.delete(0, buffer.length());
            throw new CatsException("There are some differences in the files.");
        }

        System.out.println("Exiting now ...");
    }
```

The above code is taking too much time to execute.

Comment: Huh?  Please clarify.

Comment: Do you need some more info.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're asking, but my guess is that whatever your problem might be it will probably be fixed by moving the `Iterator<String> targetMessageIterator = ...` line inside of the outer `while` loop

Comment: and consider to use for loop instead of iterator.

Comment: yes it could be ..I tried with this also but it is taking too much time to execute.. Because the list1 is having 100 records and list2 having 1000 records. So for list1 record1 - compared with each record in list2. And then in list1 record2 - compared with each record in list2. So there could be 100*1000 = 10000 records to be compared, which is taking time to execute. Please provide the inputs.

Comment: To speed things up you can create maps of `getCorpValue(message).toLowerCase()` to collection of `message` for both the sorce and target lists, then match the messages based on the maps instead of looping over both lists like this.

Comment: Why not use the `.contains(String)` method of the arraylist class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speed things up:

```
HashMap<String, String> lowers = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (String source : source_messageList) {
    lowers.put(getCorpValue(source).toLowerCase(), source);
}
for (String target : target_messageList) {
    final String corpTarget = getCorpValue(target).toLowerCase();
    if(lowers.containsKey(corpTarget)) {
        assertXMLEquals(
            convertSwiftMessageToXML(lowers.get(corpTarget)),
            convertSwiftMessageToXML(target)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Works well. But i think lowers.contains(corpTarget) should be replaced by lowers.containsKey(corpTarget).